# simple_form with two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, simple-form

This is my creation form for Customer model.

While populating `customers` table I am inserting some data in `managers` table as well. But I want to add a `date picker` in this `simple_form` but that `date` is only stored in `Manger` model and Customer model doesn't have date field. How do I do it? What alternative options I have?

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "customers" %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default center" id="new-width">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= simple_form_for @customer do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :name,:autocomplete => :off %>
          <%= f.input :principalAmount,:autocomplete => :off %>
          <%= f.input :interestRate %>
          <%= f.input :accountType %>
          <%= f.input :duration,:autocomplete => :off %>
          <%= f.button :submit %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: `Manager` model has many field which is independent of `Customer` model. But When a customer is created it has to add a date in `Manager` model which is absent in the `Customer` model.

Comment: This question is very fuzzy. I'm guessing you mean Manager.  What is the relation between the customer and relation model? Whats the actual desired outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in customers model.
Something like this:

In customer model,

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :managers
```

In view page,inside the existing form

```
<%= f.fields_for :managers do |m| %>
    <%= m.date_field :date %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How do I access that nested field value in a controller?

Comment: params will be like {customers: {name: "foo", managers: {date: "10/10/2016"}}}

Comment: you can permit easily

Answer (score 2):

You can always add a getter and setter to the customer model and manually set the manager fields.  Again it depends on the relationship with manager, if it exists already, etc.  but the main point is you can create methods that can then be accessed in the form as customer methods.

```
# in customer.rb

def manager_date=(date)
  manager.date = date
end

def manager_date
  manager.date
end
```

then in the form

```
<%= f.input :manager_date %>
```

Note - this is a brief example, you'll need to save the manager somewhere and doing this before or after the customer is updated will depend on your needs.

Another way to do this is to create an attr_accessor for manager_date in customer and if it's there, update the manager after the customer is saved

```
after_save :update_manager

def update_manager
  manager.date = manager_date
  manager.save
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a hidden attribute in Customer and pass it to Manager?

Comment: Yes - we do this all the time.  It doesn't work with has_many, but it's great for has_one or belongs_to.

Comment: it has has_may, I will go with your answer.